# using javascript variable in form

Tags: javascript, php, variables

Below is a user_id value that I obtained in the script

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      url: "/index.php?ctl=user&act=userdetail",
      async: true,
      success: function(result) {
        var user;
        user = result.user
        var user_id = user.id
      }
    })
  </script>
```

I want to send this user_id value in the form below, but I could not find how to add it to the value part. Is there any other way to post this to that page or?

```
 <div class="card shadow">
          <ul>
            <li class="pack">100 Points</li>
            <li id="one" class="price bottom-bar">$79,99</li>
            <li class="bottom-bar">100 Points</li>
            <form action="test.php" method="post">
              <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="$79,99">
              <input type="hidden" name="package" value="100 Points">
              //Here I want to send the user_id value.
              <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Send">
            </form>
          </ul>
        </div>

<div class="card shadow">
              <ul>
                <li class="pack">200 Points</li>
                <li id="one" class="price bottom-bar">$179,99</li>
                <li class="bottom-bar">200 Points</li>
                <form action="test.php" method="post">
                  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="$179,99">
                  <input type="hidden" name="package" value="200 Points">
                  //Here I want to send the user_id value.
                  <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Send">
                </form>
              </ul>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the AJAX callback function you could dynamically generate and add a new hidden input element that takes the value from the ajax response, like this:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: "/index.php?ctl=user&act=userdetail",
  async: true,
  success: function(result) {
    var user = result.user;
    var user_id = user.id;
    
    var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type='hidden';
        input.value=user_id;
        input.name='user_id';
        
    document.querySelector('form').appendChild( input );
  }
})
```

Or, add the hidden input manually and assign the value in the callback. Either way the form would have that field in the submitted data.

ie:

```
<div class="card shadow">
  <ul>
    <li class="pack">100 Points</li>
    <li id="one" class="price bottom-bar">$79,99</li>
    <li class="bottom-bar">100 Points</li>
    <form action="test.php" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="$79,99">
      <input type="hidden" name="package" value="100 Points">
      <input type='hidden' name='user_id' disabled /><!-- input is here but disabled -->
      <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Send">
    </form>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And then to target and populate the hidden input

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: "/index.php?ctl=user&act=userdetail",
  async: true,
  success: function(result) {
    var user = result.user;
    var user_id = user.id;
    
    var input = document.querySelector('form input[name="user_id"]')
        input.disabled=false;
        input.value=user_id;
  }
})
```

---

In response to the question asked in the comment - regarding multiple forms.
You could potentially do this in several ways - what I offer here is the first thing that came to mind and might not be the best ( it also has not been tested for errors either! )

Essentially the same - you create a new input element and assign the values etc but you do it for every form that matches the pattern specified in `querySelectorAll`

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: "/index.php?ctl=user&act=userdetail",
  async: true,
  success: function(result) {
    document.querySelectorAll('form[action="test.php"]').forEach(
        n=>{
            let input=document.createElement('input');
                input.type='hidden';
                input.value=result.user.id;
                input.name='user_id';
            n.appendChild( input );
        }
    );
  }
});
```

That said - knowing that there are 2 ( & probably more? ) forms a better method might be to use ajax and FormData objects.... food for thought perhaps?!

Comment: Pleasure  - glad that it helped!

Comment: So if we think that there are 3 forms, how can I send them separately in this way?I updated the question so if I have 2 buttons, it only goes in one of the two forms.

Comment: $(function () {
            $("#btn1").click(function () {
               document.querySelector('.form1').appendChild(input);
            });
        });
        $(function () {
            $("#btn2").click(function () {
               document.querySelector('.form2').appendChild(input);
            });
        });